# Invalid ACL identifier

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Im trying to make a REST API call from db and for that i have tried to create a ACL first.Below are the query,I tried to execute via sysdba user.Im getting error.
Can someone help me.

```
    BEGIN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (
        acl          => 'test_sx_acl_file.xml',
        description  => 'A test of the ACL functionality',
        principal    => 'node',
        is_grant     => TRUE,
        privilege    => 'connect',
        start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
        end_date     => NULL);
    end; 
    /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

2)
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl ( acl => 'test_sx_acl_file.xml ', host => '*.testapi.com', lower_port => NULL, upper_port => NULL);
END;
/
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-46059: Invalid ACL identifier specified
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 70
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 484
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Why is that? what could be the reason

Comment: You have a space character at the end of the file name: `acl => 'test_sx_acl_file.xml '` vs. `acl => 'test_sx_acl_file.xml'`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Thanks it worked.Hmm , im not sure on how i missed those little details.I was thinking on access of ACL.